# How to use three map() with multiple variables in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, mapping

I have three Image Collections. The first one is aerosol concentration, the second one is angle value, and the last one is what I want to give radiance values. For each pixel, I can extract radiance from excel according to their `aerosol` (as row index) and `angle` (as column index) information.  How to do this thing in GEE.

I think I have to create three `map()` loops which is what I did but still meet errors. For example, I masked all pixels in image3 when `aerosol==1` and `angle==40`, and extracted radiance value in excel according to `aerosol`'s row and `angle`'s column, here I put an example:

```
// read aerosol

var aodValues1 = listAOD2.map(function(aa1){
  var image1 = newimageCollection_clear_BWSA.first()
  return ee.Image.constant(ee.Number.parse(aa1).multiply(0.01)).copyProperties(image1)
});

// read angle

var angleValue1 = ee.List.sequence(0, 89).map(function(j){
  var image1 = newimageCollection_clear_BWSA.first();
  var anglevalue1 =  ee.Image.constant(j).copyProperties(image1);
  return anglevalue1;
});

// read table info

var table_info = table.getInfo();
var featureList = ee.FeatureCollection(table_info.features).toList(ee.FeatureCollection(table_info.features).size());

// extract radiance value

var dsr = function(image) {
  //read each image in imagecollection
  var inputCRS = image.select(0).projection()
  var inputScale = image.select(0).projection().nominalScale()
  var sza = image.select('cosSZA').multiply(180/Math.PI)
  var aod = image.select('Optical_Depth_055')

  var newbandzong = aodValues1.map(function(aodvalue1){
    var newbandzong0= angleValue1.map(function(anglevalue1){
      
      var maskzong = aod.multiply(100).round().divide(100).eq(aodvalue1)
        .add(sza.multiply(100).round().divide(100).eq(anglevalue1))
      var ii = aodValues1.indexOf(aodvalue1)
      // read excel value according to SZA and aod information
      var specificValueImage = ee.Image.constant(ee.Feature(featureList.get(j0)).get(ee.String(listAOD.get(ii))))
      // mask pixels that meet maskzong image and others were set as -1
      var maskedImage= specificValueImage.updateMask(maskzong.eq(1))
      var updatedImage = maskedImage.where(maskedImage.eq(0), -1)
//   newbandzong0 = newbandzong0.addBands(updatedImage)
      return updatedImage.copyProperties(image)
    })
    // newbandzong is a list of image, through max value to a single image
    var newbandzongCollection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(newbandzong0);
    var maxvalue0 =newbandzongCollection.reduce(ee.Reducer.max());
    return maxvalue0;
  })

  var newbandzongImage = ee.Image.cat(newbandzong);
  var maxvalue = newbandzongImage.reduce(ee.Reducer.max()).rename('dsr');
  // put the result in original iamges one by one
  return image.addBands(maxvalue).copyProperties(image);
};
```

I don't know if this code is right, but I always meet errors such as:

> there is an error: ImageCollection (Error) Error in
> map(ID=2018_01_01): List.map: A mapped algorithm must take one
> argument.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You're just trying to do a 2D LUT?

Comment: yes, i just want to extract LUT values to specific pixels according to angle and aerosol information. I created three map() function but they didn't work.